# Will Java 11 and onwards be supported by Syndesis?

Tags: syndesis

I was quite surprised that the only options of Java supported by Syndesis are 8 and 9. Was wondering if more modern editions will be supported any time soon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just ask them? https://gitter.im/syndesisio/community?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge

Comment: That's what I just did on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Syndesis project is no longer maintained and developed.